# Visual Studio 2015 TFS New build definition button not showing up?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I am using VS2015 and am connected to my TFS. However when i click Team Explorer/Builds, the "New Build Definition" button does not show up. The strange thing is this all works in VS2013. Is there a toolkit i am possibly missing or is the button hidden? Not sure what i could be overlooking for the button to not show up in one version and show up in the other...

Comment: Are you using VS2015 RTM or VS2015 Update 1? Do you actually have permission to create/edit builds? I wouldn't be surprised if it were as simple as "the button always shows up in 2013, but only shows up if you actually have permission to create builds" in 2015.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but i am using getting the permissions issue in both environments. It's just weird that the build definition button shows up in 13 but not 15. The new VS might just not show the button until permissions are allowed. I have forwarded Microsoft configuration guide to our TFS person to aid in setting it up. I'll post back when i have an update!

Answer (score 1):

Open page **Team Foundation Server** in browser. And open your project. And find tab **Build**.

You need to update the application VS2015.

Or open in VS **TeamExplorer** then **Builds** and:

> Build Definitions -> Actions -> Security...

and configure security access control.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have expanded the Build Definitions by clicking the triangle:

[image]

Comment: in 15, there is no button under the first option but there is one under XAML. I still get the same permission error but weird that the button shows for one and not the other.

Comment: Do you mean you can't see "New build definition" under "Build Definitions", but you can see it under "XAML Build Definitions"? Are you able to see the button in VS 2015 on another client machine with your credential? If you use another user account to connect TFS in VS 2015 on your client machine, are you able to see the button? As you mentioned you have permission issue, you need to ask team project admin to grant you permission by going to Build Definitions -Actions -Security, and add your account.

Comment: "Do you mean you can't see "New build definition" under "Build Definitions", but you can see it under "XAML Build Definitions"?" is exactly what i am seeing in 15.